# Excel - Dynamic pie chart linked to drop-down list

Tags: excel, google-sheets, charts, ms-office, spreadsheet

I want to create a pie chart that shows the status of a certain process (i.e. how many lines are "Done", how many are "In Progress", etc.)

I have a column that contains a drop-down list with the statuses that I'm working on, and now I want to create the chart that will update automatically when I change the status from "In Progress" to "Done".

Is there a way to do this on Excel/Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this on Google Sheets?

you can try like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think that this would work on Sheets but not on Excel, for some reason...